# Calculating dihedral 6 factor group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let H={$\rho_{0}, \rho_{2}, \rho_{4}$}, a subgroup of D6, the group of symmetries.  Where $\rho_{0}$=identity permutation, $\rho_{2}$=(1,3,5)(2,4,6) and $\rho_{4}$=(1,5,3)(2,6,4).

I am trying to calculate D6 the dihedral group of 6 gons  ' factor group, D6/H. Here is what I have so far but I am stuck.

Notice that H is generated by $\rho_2$  Which is isomorphic to the set of integers mod 3. Which leads to D6/Z3. What should I do next? And how donI express this in the form of cycles?